# $\operatorname{rank}(T^3) + \operatorname{rank}(T) \geq 2\operatorname{rank}(T^2)$ for finite-dimensional $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Consider a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over the field $\mathbb{F}$ with a linear operator $T.$ Prove that we have $\operatorname{rank}(T^3) + \operatorname{rank}(T) \geq 2 \operatorname{rank}(T^2).$

First, let us assume that $\dim_{\mathbb{F}}(V) = n.$ Our immediate observations include that $T^3(V) \subseteq T^2(V) \subseteq T(V)$ so that $\operatorname{rank}(T^3) \leq \operatorname{rank}(T^2) \leq \operatorname{rank}(T)$ and $\operatorname{rank}(T^3) \geq \operatorname{rank}(T) + \operatorname{rank}(T^2) - n$ by Sylvester's Rank Inequality. Can we do some manipulations with what we have to get the desired inequality, or do we require something else?

Comment: I have been thinking of incorporating the Rank-Nullity Theorem and the fact that $\ker(T^3) \supseteq \ker(T^2) \supseteq \ker(T)$ so that $\operatorname{nullity}(T^3) \geq \operatorname{nullity}(T^2) \geq \operatorname{nullity}(T).$

Comment: This problem is a special case of the Frobenius Rank Inequality (which is implied by Sylvester's Rank Inequality)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the linear map $T':T(V)\rightarrow T^2(V)/T^3(V)$ by $T'(v)=T(v)+T^3(V)$.

The quotient vector space $T^2(V)/T^3(V)$ has dimension $\text{rank}(T^2)-\text{rank}(T^3)$ as $T^3(V)$ is a proper subspace of $T^{2}(V)$.

Now, notice that $T'$ is surjective and that $T^2(V)\subset \text{Ker}(T')$, therefore from rank nullity theorem we obtain
$\text{rank}(T)-\text{rank}(T^2)\geq \text{rank}(T^2)-\text{rank}(T^3)$. By rearranging the previous inequality we conclude the result.

Comment: And more generally,  with essentially the same argument, we have $$\text{rank}(T^{k+1})+\text{rank}(T^{k-1})\geq 2\,\text{rank}(T^k)$$ for all $k=1,2,3,\ldots$.

Comment: Excellent! I have never much used quotient spaces, but this is a most interesting case where it seems to be the only argument that can be made. Thank you very much.